# Не собирается SDL2 программа с MinGW

Tags: windows, mingw, sdl2

Дано:

- 32-битная Windows XP
- 32-битный MinGW с gcc
- 32-битные dev-версии SDL2, SDL2_image и SDL2_ttf, распакованные в `C:\MinGW\lib` и `C:\MinGW\include` (знаю, что это некрасиво, но я пренебрежительно отношусь к винде и мне б хоть как-нибудь :) (вытащены `i686-blabla` каталоги отсюда: [SDL](https://libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.4-mingw.tar.gz), [SDL_image](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-devel-2.0.1-mingw.tar.gz), [SDL_ttf](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.14-mingw.tar.gz))
- Простенькая сишная программка, которая успешно собирается и работает под линуксом без каких-либо пинков

Проблема: не линкуется. Методом гуглинга, копипаста и научного тыка собрал такую команду, выдающую минимум ошибок:

`mingw32-gcc -Wall -Dmain=SDL_main -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf src\*.c -o myprog.exe`

Это я уже кое-как решил проблемы с ненаходящимися инклудами и дублирующимся main'ом (мой main прописан как `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` по советам гугла). Однако при попытке собрать всё сыпет ошибками:

```
Temp\ccOZXxwh.o:amtile.c:(.text+0x6ee):
  undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
Temp\ccOZXxwh.o:amtile.c:(.text+0x734):
  undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
Temp\ccOZXxwh.o:amtile.c:(.text+0x759):
  undefined reference to `SDL_GetWindowSurface'
Temp\ccOZXxwh.o:amtile.c:(.text+0x770):
  undefined reference to `IMG_Init'
Temp\ccOZXxwh.o:amtile.c:(.text+0x810):
  undefined reference to `TTF_Init'
Temp\ccOZXxwh.o:amtile.c:(.text+0x830):
  undefined reference to `TTF_OpenFont'
```

Ну и так далее. Пробовал прописывать `-LC:\MinGW\lib`, проверял наличие соответствующих `*.a` файлов там — всё есть, а не собирается.

Что я делаю не так и как делать как надо?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian дописал в вопрос

Comment: А сам mingw [отсюда](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php)?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian да

Comment: Попробовал у себя, `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>\n int main(int, char**){SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);}` собирается нормально строкой `g++ main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o main.exe`  (win10x64, msys64)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian внезапно работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот уж к чему я никак не был готов — так к это важности порядка аргументов.

Было (убрал несущественное):

`gcc -Wall -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf src\*.c -o myprog.exe`

Стало:

`gcc -Wall src\*.c -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -o myprog.exe`

То есть просто переставил список файлов в начало — и всё сразу собралось, запустилось, всё хорошо.

При этом линуксу на порядок аргументов плевать — собирает и так, и так.

---

Пояснение [отсюда](http://staff.mmcs.sfedu.ru/~ulysses/IT/C++/using_gcc.html):

> Здесь, в отличие от рассмотренных ранее случаев, порядок аргументов `g++` важен, поскольку `-L` и `-l` это опции линковщика, который вступает в работу *после* компилятора, обрабатывающего первый аргумент (имя файла).

Comment: Ещё и сам порядок перечисления библиотек важен, например если поставить `-lmingw32` в конец, то будет ошибка `undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'`

Answer (score -1):

1. ЧТЯДНТ - собираете программу в форточке. Если вам привычен Linux, поставьте mingw32-cross-gcc и собирайте программу из Linux, но с целевой платформой Windows
2. Используйте любой генератор Makefile, чтобы не заниматься нудной ручной работой. Это могут быть qmake, cmake, automake или qbs. Выбирайте.

Comment: Согласен по поводу автоматизации сборки тем же cmake-ом. Но не согласен, что собирать в Windows под Windows это "делать не так".

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian сборка под Windows требует огромного количества суеты. Хотябы по причине отсутствия пакетного менеджера - любую зависимость приходится гуглить. По Linux достаточно подключить репозитарий mingw32 и докачивать недостающее из него.

Comment: частично соглашусь, но например та же сборка msys64 включает пакетный менеджер pacman, и установка например dev буста это всего лишь `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-boost`

Comment: За что минус? Решение как минимум интересное, т.к. наличие "сборочного цеха" в одном месте - это лучше, нежели чем куча отдельных под каждую систему. Да, возможно всплывут какие-либо нюансы, но где их не бывает.

Comment: Минус наверное за то, что ответ не соответствует вопросу - как заставить собираться проект в MinGW в Windows XP.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian MinGW, наверное, является кроссплатформенным ПО.

Comment: Это всё хорошо, приму к сведению и потыкаю (хотя вообще с cmake уже работал), но не совсем ответ на вопрос :)